# Need help in Laravel 8 search query

Tags: laravel, select, laravel-8

I am working on a search query. my requirement is that

An employee can search for job seekers with multiple languages and levels of language

for example:

employee enter

```
[
    ['name'=>'English', 'level'=>'fluant']
]
```

now my requirement is that every job seeker who has the English language with basic, advanced, and fluent language levels are selected.

or if an employee enter

```
[
   ['name'=>'English', 'level'=>'advanced']
]
```

then all job seekers with English languages and basic and advanced levels are selected.

how can I write the select query in Laravel 8?

I am using this query

```
$levels = LanguageSkills::where('language_id', $lang[2])->where(function($q) {
                    $q->where('level', 'like', '%basic%')
                    ->orWhere('level', 'like', '%advanced%')
                    ->orwhere('level', 'like', '%fluent%');
                })->first();
```

but I'm a little bit confused with this query. Is there any other way or can rewrite this query with a working state.

Comment: Why not use numeric levels? basic = 1, advanced = 2, fluent = 3. Then just get skills where the level is `<= 3` for example to get all basic, advanced and fluent skills

Comment: I agree with @brombeer. it will be very fast than this logic. However, if you can't change column type, I think you can use 'whereIn' condition (if in level column stored one word)

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to SQL I'd probably go for sth like

```sql
SELECT first_name
FROM language_skills
WHERE language_id = < id >
  AND CASE
          WHEN level = 'basic' THEN 0
          WHEN level = 'advanced' THEN 1
          WHEN level = 'fluent' THEN 2
      END >= 1;
```

To put it into your Laravel model, you could create eloquent scope and some kind of "LanguageSkillLevelEnum" to keep your values in one place.

```
public function scopeLvlAtLeast($query, $lvl) 
{
    return $query->whereRaw(<<<SQL
      CASE
          WHEN level = 'basic' THEN 0
          WHEN level = 'advanced' THEN 1
          WHEN level = 'fluent' THEN 2
      END >= ?
SQL, $lvl);
}

public function scopeLvlAtMost($query, $lvl) 
{
    return $query->whereRaw(<<<SQL
      CASE
          WHEN level = 'basic' THEN 0
          WHEN level = 'advanced' THEN 1
          WHEN level = 'fluent' THEN 2
      END <= ?
SQL, $lvl);
}
```

(question mark comes as protection from SQL injection. You can read more about it [here](https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/sql-injection-prevention-laravel/#example-2-use-of-dbstatement))

Then to use it in your example you should

```
$levels = LanguageSkills::where('language_id', $lang[2])->lvlAtMost(1)->first();
$levels2 = LanguageSkills::where('language_id', $lang[2])->lvlAtLeast(2)->first();
```